# Write XML in visual basic

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to write following element to an XML file:

```
<ns2:IntraConsignment IntraListingsNbr="1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment" xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon">
```

Currently the line looks like:

```
<ns2:IntraConsignment IntraListingsNbr="1" xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment">
```

I'm using following code:

```
 XmlWrt.WriteStartElement"ns2", "IntraConsignment", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment")
 XmlWrt.WriteAttributeString("IntraListingsNbr", "1")
 XmlWrt.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon")
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: How can you correct *what*?

Comment: I'm not aware of *anything* that treats the *order* of namespace declarations (On a single element) as significant.

Comment: I'm also not sure about that. If the order doesn't affect the working, there's no problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Namespace scoping)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#scoping):

> The scope of a namespace declaration declaring a prefix extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner declarations with the same NSAttName part

So that means that two namespace declarations within the same start-tag have exactly the same scope. Which, in turn, implies that there's no significance to the *order* in which declarations appear.

The only place I can see where this might be ambiguous is if, within the same start-tag, you attempted to declare two namespaces using the *same* prefix. <strike>I can't (at the moment) find a specific prohibition on this, but I'm fairly sure most XML processors wouldn't like it.</strike> But that's not possible - despite their special meaning, namespace declarations are still attributes, and you're not allowed to apply the same attribute multiple times to the same element.